# Uploading to Windows App store

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows

I am trying to figure out if I can upload a Visual Studio 2013 Desktop application to the Windows App store? I am not sure but I think you have to use Visual Studio 2015. I have not been able to find too much information on this.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root

Comment: Thank you so much!